# How to blend two different images together with similar features using feature matching in OpenCV-Python?

Tags: python, opencv

Say if I have two different images but for instance an object in both of the images is the same. How would I use the matching objects as a point to match both images together and blend them into each other? The images would both be of the same resolution and size.

Comment: You can go through the [stitching pipeline](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/stitching/doc/introduction.html) with only difference being feature detection - in your case you will need to discard all features which are not related to your object.

Comment: I have the code working now however I still can't figure out a way to discard the feature points. Is there an example out there of how to drop features? @DmitriiZ.

Comment: Do you know which points you need to discard?

Comment: I have found the points I need to discard and can print them to the terminal with the following line of code. I'm using ORB for feature matching. [ORB doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html) `for m in matches: print(m.distance)`

Comment: My bad actually this is the distance for the feature matching. The points are gotten later on with `kp1[m.queryIdx].pt` and `kp2[m.trainIdx].pt` .

Comment: Any ideas @DmitriiZ. ? The problem is I still don't know how to drop some of the kp1 and kp2 points to remove the matching points I don't want. I can't seem to find documentation on how to do this either.

Comment: Can't you just remove them from whatever array you are using? Maybe if you add a code snippet - it would become a bit clearer